# What is the correct way to wrap file names with space when download files via FTP

Tags: c#, ftp

I have written a FTP client ( To learn).

Im having problems when handling with spaces. What is the accepted solution for this ( Preferably one that works with "all" ftp servers).
I have tried:
1)Just sending the path name.
2)Sending "FileName With Space.omg"
3)Sending \"FileName With Space.omg\"

Version 3 "works" with getting filesize, in terms the server returns a size 0(Its NOT actualy 0 sized file), but when doing this method for download the server does not accept it.


If it mathers to ppl, this is on a windows mobile and .NET compact framework 2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the spaces? (" " --> "%20")

Comment: Try escaping the spaces by putting a backslash (\\) before the space. Like this: FileName\ With\ Space.omg